# How do I resize picture in Python

Tags: python

I have a picture like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crcri.jpg)

I want to crop the image as the red rectangle show.
As result I want to have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syi2g.png)

Which is in the same size as the original above.

How do I do that in python ?

Comment: Have you tried using the pillow library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pillow to do that. Eg.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Yoda.png")
new = im.crop((leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY))
new = new.resize(im.size)
new.save("Yodaonly.png")
```

Check about Pillow and it's installation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Shambav's method, you can use [`cv2`](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) (which you can install with `pip install opencv-python`). Note that `cv2` is in general more performant than `PIL`.

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

# Get original image size
h, w, _ = img.shape

# Crop
img = img[top: bottom, left: right]

# Resize
img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h))

# Note that you can choose your preferred interpolation method for resizing, e.g.
# img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Save 
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", img)
```